# Annoying highlighting behaviour

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed

On the questions list, the questions that have one of the tags one has in his favorites, are highlighted with yellowish color (I would call it "yellow" for the sake of shortness), like this:

[image]

If I chose to show only the questions of a specific tag, they all appear as normal (well, this is expected). 
Let's take the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag as an example. So I'm browsing the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (it's in my favorites) questions, and then a new question appears. "1 question with new activity" notification is displayed. I click on it to see the newly added question, and what happens next is that all the list goes yellow:

[image]

While this is not really a big issue, I find this really annoying. It also doesn't make sense to highlight favorite-tagged questions if I'm *already* looking at the list of favorite-tagged questions. Is this by-design? Or maybe there's a problem on my side? I'm under FF 16.0.2 under linux if it's related in any way, no user-scripts.

Comment: It should only highlight if two or more tags are in your favorites. But yes, all the ones appearing from the "new activity" are in indeed highlighted.

Comment: @Mysticial, well, I have just one tag in my favs at the moment, yet it's still highlighting

Comment: It looks like a highlighting issue with C++ specifically, we have our best man on it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a bug in the way tags with + were handled - this will be fixed in the next build.